# .htaccess no funciona después de editarlo

Tags: .htaccess

Tenía el fichero .htaccess funcionando para que me redirecione `wwww.midominio` a `midominio`, pero lo he editado y ahora no consigo que vuelva a funcionar.
He restaurado una copia que tenia renombrada como .htaccess_back, cambiando el nombre a .htaccess pero esto tampoco me funciona.

El archivo es encuentra en `/home/admin/web/midominio.com/public_html` y no funciona una única configuración que tengo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.midominio.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://midominio.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

tengo un servidor apache con tomcat como contenedor de archivos.

Por favor, ¿me podeis dar alguna pista para volver a construir mi archivo?

Comment: Mira si el servidor web tiene permisos para leer el fichero.htaccess. Según como hayas restaurado el fichero, los permisos y el usuario/grupo pueden haber cambiado.

Comment: Si tiene rw-r--r-- como permisos, diría que no es por eso, pero gracias de todos modos por el comentario.

Comment: Puede ser que, al haber implementado otro .htaccess con otras reglas, tu navegador haya grabado en caché un redireccionamiento, y que ahora siga intentando acceder a otro recurso.. Probá con otro navegador o [eliminando el caché](http://superuser.com/q/304589/527470)

Comment: Me pasó igual. Pero no lo edité con el bloc de notas como siempre lo hacía, lo edité con Dreamweaver y me funcionó.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer una redirección 301, con Tomcat no se basa en .htaccess. Podeis ver información en :

ya he conseguido que funcione siguiendo los consejos de este link
http://nematodes.org/martin/2010/02/04/301-permanent-redirect-with-tomcat-howto/

Comment: Información adicional en
https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/friendlyurlrewritefilter/
http://rm-rf.es/url-rewriting-reescritura-de-url-en-tomcat/#comment-144209

Answer (score 0):

¿Por casualidad tu sitio es manejado a través de Wordpress? Si es afirmativo, para redirigir tu sitio de www.tudominio.com a tudominio.com no tienes que hacer nada en el .htaccess , sino que debes hacerlo desde el escritorio de Wordpress:
**Ajustes/Ajustes generales/Dirección del sitio (URL)**
ahí pones tudominio.com y listo.

Acabo de probarlo con mi dominio y funciona. Pero antes... borra o comenta los posibles intentos de redireccionamiento que hayas hecho en este sentido en tu .htaccess

Saludos.

Comment: No uso wordpress, de cualquier forma, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Aunque no uses Wordpress, si usas cualquier otro gestor de contenidos (Joomla, Drupal...) podrías mirar en los ajustes y hacer la redirección desde allí. O bien mirar la configuración DNS del manejador de dominio o del hosting. Es posible que haya en alguna otra parte  una redirección que prima sobre la que intentas poner en tu .htaccess.

Comment: Gracias, miraré en esta linea a ver que puede haber con una configuración que cree el conflicto.

Answer (score -2):

Prueba lo *siguiente*:

```
# No mostrar www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.tudominio.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://tudominio.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

**Solo por si acaso**, fíjate si el *archivo* `.htaccess` no tiene *extensión* `.txt`

Comment: Falta un espacio antes del último parámetro en la condición... ¿y qué sentido tiene poner NC a `.*`? Además, ¿por qué eliminaste el QSA, que es importante?

Comment: He copiado el código tal y como comentas, he borrado las caches de mis navegadores y tambien había verificado que el fichero no tiene extensión alguna. 
He reiniciado apache y tomcat.
Tendré que investigar un poco más para ver que está ocurriendo.
Edito desde windows 10 con notepad ++, no con codificacion UTF-8, no sé si estaré metiendo algun caracter raro.
Sigue sin funcionar.